# How to fix the "Not Acceptable 406" error with arabic language in url?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

How to fix the "Not Acceptable 406" error with arabic language in url ?

> Not Acceptable
>
> An appropriate representation of the
>   requested resource / could not be
>   found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error
>   was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the reque

The error doesn't appear when I put english words in the url :
http://www.faressoft.org/?anything=hello

but it appears when I put arabic words in the url :
http://www.faressoft.org/?anything=%E3%D1%CD%C8%C7%F0

I have this problem in all pages.

Comment: I guess that the error is not caused by apache but by the script that is handling the request (and parsing the querystring parameters).

Comment: but I have this problem in all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, this can be a lot of things. First of all, do you have mod_security? That's an Apache module supposedly making your site more secure however without a real lot of understanding of it just breaks your site. Just switch it off.

Comment: Yes, My hoster has mod_security in his hosting. How can I disabled it (I have a shared hosting not a server).

Comment: I guess this answer and my answer are related. And disabling mod_security might not solve your problem. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is probably configured to the character set UTF-8. But the end of your URL decodes to the byte sequence E3D1CDC8C7F0, which is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence. That's probably why Apache raises an error.

In what character set is E3D1CDC8C7F0 a valid byte sequence? What information does the HTTP header contain about the character set (you can use the HTTP Live Header plug-in for Firefox to find out)?

**Update:**

Obviously, my answer got downvoted (without any comments). However, the accepted answer and my answer are related. My answer gives the technical details and the accepted answer explains which module is responsible for the check.

I still don't understand how the URL in your question was created in the first place. I don't think it's a valid URL.

I've copied some arabic text from your web site, URL encoded it and created the following URL, which works:

http://www.faressoft.org/?anything=%D9%87%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%83

When the page is displayed, the URL is even displayed with arabic characters in Firefox.

Are you sure, disabling mod_security will solve your problem? What if your URL is wrong?

P.S.: As I don't understand any Arabic I hope I didn't copy any text that is insulting or confusing in this new context.